# How to determine bluetooth hardware classes on Android devices?

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware

I know this is a hardware question, but I am still hopeful I can get a little help. The question is: How can I figure out what class (hardware specification) a bluetooth chip is within an android device?

I would like to use class 1 radio's in some in shop devices, but there is no point if an android device (phone or otherwise) can't support the range. Does anyone know how to determine the hardware class of a device bluetooth chip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately there are no public APIs to get this information programmatically

Most phones use Class 2 Bluetooth devices.
If you know the exact device name / model we can find the class of device by looking up the bluetooth qualification details - it will list the chip in use and its device class.